# There is something wrong with my calculations in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn python and as a test i tried to make a BMI calculator

```
#BMI Calculator

name = raw_input ("What is your name?: ")
weight = raw_input ("Hello %s What is your weight? (kilo): "% (name))
height = raw_input ("And what is your height? (cm) ")

#Calculations: weight / height^2 * 10000

weight = int(weight)
height = int(height)

BMI = (weight / height ** 2) * 10000

print "%s, your BMI is %s"% (name, BMI)
```

But there seems to be something wrong with the calculations because i always end up with a BMI of 0? whats wrong?

Comment: You're using Python 2, I presume? Unless you are morbidly obese, `height` will be greater than `weight`, so the answer will be zero as per the dup.

Comment: change this line BMI = (weight / height ** 2) * float(10000)

Comment: even better BMI = (weight / float(height) ** 2) * 10000

Answer (score 2):

In Python and several languages `/` is the operator for "integer division." For example, in Python, try:

```
num = 1 / 2 # Comes out to be 0
```

Rather, make sure that one of the numbers involved in your division calculation is a float:

```
num = 1.0 / 2 # Comes out to be 0.5!
```

In your scenario, since `height` and `weight` are integers, it's accidentally doing integer division!

You can also cast variables to floats, like so:

```
weight_f = float(weight)
```